# Service Worker error. Not working on live(https) server

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

Every thing is working fine at localhost but when i upload same file to live server i got below mentioned error.

```
Service Worker error : DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!
Thank you

Comment: Load chrome://serviceworker-internals/ and check 'Open DevTools window and pause JavaScript execution on Service Worker startup for debugging.'

Comment: _“The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')”_ – your server is not sending a correct Content-Type header for the script.

Answer (score 2):

A Service Worker script [has to be served using a JavaScript media type](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#update-algorithm) i.e. either of `text/javascript`, `application/javascript` or `application/x-javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be wrong path to your Service Worker.

Comment: funny enough, this was my reason :)

Answer (score 0):

ServiceWorker supported MIME type are 'text/javascript', application/javascript and application/x-javascript. got to ur server file and set

```
response.writeHead(201, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your time and efforts.I am finally able to solve the problem. The problem occur because i use .htaccess to modify my url. At modified url main.js is not able to load the sw.js.

Comment: can you share your answer here? I got an error too
`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`