# Service Worker not loading on live(https) server

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, vue.js, service-worker

When on localhost the `service-worker.js` loads and works just fine, but on the live server it's not loading and I get this error in the console:

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/x-js').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/x-js').
```

There is a redirect from http to https with a `.htaccess` which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

- I know this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39241762/9710118), but not fully answered.
- I know it might have something to do with the .htaccess file like
  mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314650/9710118).
- It could also have something to do with the vue.js framework pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566060/9710118)

But in the end I can't get my head around this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your live server should return HTTP response header `content-type` with a value of "application/javascript".  Instead it's returning "text/x-js".  Ideally, UTF8 should be also be supported.  Try adding these lines to `.htaccess` to correct the MIME type for all *.js URIs:

```
AddType application/javascript .js 
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

Inspect the HTTP response headers in Chrome DevTools to ensure that the server responds with header `content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8` when you request your service-worker.js URL